# Perdendo Session após requisição

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, session

Bom galera, estou com um problema que até agora não consegui resolver. Ele só começa a ocorrer depois de uma **requisição ajax**, sendo que nela eu gero um documento e retorno a **url** em um **json**, para ser pego no **javascript**, ser atribuído a um link e ser feito o download.

Como ocorre: após gerar o primeiro relatório, se o usuário tentar criar outro logo em seguida, a aplicação meio que chama o **Application_Start** novamente, e assim, perdendo a "linkagem" que tinha da **session**. O engraçado é que no browser (estou utilizando o **Chrome**), a session continua aparecendo nos Cookies.

Outra fato interessante, é que quando eu clico no link pra fazer o download, ele também chama novamente o **Application_Start**...

**NT:** Utilizo ASPNET MVC 5

**Exemplo de como crio as Sessions:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult LoginRequest(string login, string pass)
    {
        string loginCache = "usuario";
        string senhaCache = "123123";

        if (login == loginCache && pass == senhaCache)
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Nome"] = "Admin";
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Email"] = loginCache;

            return Json(
                new
                {
                    sucesso = true,
                    href = "GerarRelatorio/Index"
                }
            );
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(
                new {
                    sucesso = false,
                    msg = "Login e/ou Senha estão incorretos."
                }    
            );
        }
```

**Exemplo de como estou retornando a url:**

```
        var newCaminhoContent = Path.Combine(urlDownloadFolder, arquivoModel.Nome);

        var urlDownloadHTML = ( newCaminhoContent.Substring(newCaminhoContent.IndexOf(@"Content")) );

        return Json(new
        {
            hasError = false,
            msg = "O arquivo foi gerado com sucesso!",
            href = urlDownloadHTML,
            nome = arquivoModel.Nome,
            ext = arquivoModel.ExtensaoString
        });
```

**Exemplo de como pego a url no javascript:**

```
$.post(
    AppConfig.baseUrl + "/GerarRelatorio/Gerar",
    {
        cm: cm,
        tr: tr
    },
    function (data, status) {


        console.log(data);

        try {
            if (data.hasError === false) {

                getTimeToShowLink(data);

                //var win = window.open(AppConfig.baseUrl + data.href);
                //win.focus();

                //$('#modal-status').modal('hide');
            }
            else {
                $('#div-modal-loading').hide();
                $('#div-modal-msg').html(data.msg);                    
            }
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
        finally {
            //$btn.button('reset');
            $('#modal-status').modal('hide');
        }
    }
);

function getTimeToShowLink(data) {

    $('#btn-download')
       .attr('href', AppConfig.baseUrl + data.href)
       .attr('download', data.nome)
       .show()

    var tempo = 10;
    var sec = 0;

    var interval = setInterval(function () {

        sec = pad(++sec % 60);

        if (parseInt(sec) <= parseInt(tempo)) {
            $("#div-msg-download").html(
                'Se o download não começar automaticamente em até ' + (tempo - sec) + ' segundos, clique aqui...');
        }
        else {
            $('#div-msg-download').html('Clique aqui para fazer o download...');
            clearInterval(interval);
        }

    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Pelo que entendo, você está chamando a aplicação em cors. Entendemos que o js está na máquina do cliente e que o cookie da sessão não é enviado no momento da requisição ajax, por isso, o sistema entende que é outro client requisitando...

Comment: Bom, mas você sabe como essa situação poderia ser corrigida?

Comment: Depende de várias coisas, mas pode tentar tirando a concatenação do endpoint, se o endereço for o mesmo claro. Seria possível?

Comment: Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Por exemplo, aqui: AppConfig.baseUrl + "/GerarRelatorio/Gerar", ficaria assim: "/GerarRelatorio/Gerar".
Porém, mais uma vez. Depende de como seu ambiente foi configurado, de como sua lógica foi construída...

Comment: Entendi... Irei testar aqui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom galera, só precisei mudar o **httpRuntime** pra fazer funcionar. Aparentemente a aplicação por algum motivo, atualizava o **web.config** e isso fazia com que o pool do **IIS** reiniciava toda vez que era feito uma nova requisição, chamando múltiplas vezes o método **Application_Start**.

Antes:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
```

Depois:

```
<httpRuntime fcnMode="Disabled" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
```

Isso meio que impede o **web.config** de ser atualizado, evitando o App pool de reiniciar o website.